# No "Line Break" when get data from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP coding which now I face the problem that the data that I stored in MYSQL have "Line Break" involved like this pic

[image]

But when I call them to show in table, it has no "Line Break" like this pic

[image]

As you can see in fourth and fifth block, the "Line Break" are not involved. (The third block is miracle, I don't know why but in other row it is as same as fourth and fifth block)
I have no idea why, how to fix this?

This is my code, which normal echo them in table.

```
<tr>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $PositionName; ?> </td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $Quantity; ?> </td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $JobDescription; ?> </td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $JobQualification; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $SkillRequired; ?></td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $Salary; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try printing your string using nl2br() PHP function.

```
<tr>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $PositionName; ?> </td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $Quantity; ?> </td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo nl2br($JobDescription); ?> </td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $JobQualification; ?></td>
<td align="center"><?php echo $SkillRequired; ?></td>
<td align="center"> <?php echo $Salary; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

In HTML new line characters i.e. `\n` characters are not printed.

PHP's [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function will convert new lines `\n` to `<br/>` tag so that it takes appropriate line breaks.

Example:

```
<?php echo nl2br($JobDescription); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<?php echo nl2br($var); ?>` to convert new lines to HTML line breaks.